# Pafy Youtube URL Error

Tags: python, youtube, pafy

I am trying Pafy library but seem to have encountered a problem.
This is my code:

```
a = pafy.new("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2AF8jH84o0")
```

And this is the error I am getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRKZg.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube-DL must be downloaded as well since Pafy uses it as a dependancy.

You can use Pip: `sudo -H pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

On a Mac, you can download it using homebrew instead: `brew install youtube-dl`

On Unix like machines (Mac, Linux), you can use curl:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

If Youtube-DL isn't found on your machine, Pafy usually falls back to it's internal mechanisms, which are "not as well mantained." If you really can't download Youtube-DL, you can try to use Pafy's own internal backend (not recommended) by adding the line:

`pafy.BACK_END = "internal"`

The recommended method is Youtube-DL

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, I imagine you imported the library with:

```
import pafy

a = pafy.new("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2AF8jH84o0")
```